# The system cannot find the file specified (Python 3)

Tags: python, python-3.x, image, image-processing, computer-vision

I'm trying read texts from an image using pytesseract but it throws this error no matter what I try.

**Code:**

```
import os
import subprocess
import pytesseract
from PIL import Image

subprocess.call('dir', shell=True)
print(os.path.isfile("test.jpg")) #True

im = Image.open("test.jpg")    
text = pytesseract.image_to_string(im)
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "F:/Programming/PYTHON/captcha/test/main.py", line 10, in <module>
    text = pytesseract.image_to_string(im)
  File "F:\Program Files (64bit)\Python\lib\site-packages\pytesseract\pytesseract.py", line 193, in image_to_string
    return run_and_get_output(image, 'txt', lang, config, nice)
  File "F:\Program Files (64bit)\Python\lib\site-packages\pytesseract\pytesseract.py", line 140, in run_and_get_output
    run_tesseract(**kwargs)
  File "F:\Program Files (64bit)\Python\lib\site-packages\pytesseract\pytesseract.py", line 111, in run_tesseract
    proc = subprocess.Popen(command, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
  File "F:\Program Files (64bit)\Python\lib\subprocess.py", line 709, in __init__
    restore_signals, start_new_session)
  File "F:\Program Files (64bit)\Python\lib\subprocess.py", line 997, in _execute_child
    startupinfo)
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified

Process finished with exit code 1
```

what's wrong? I know that file is there. I checked it using `os.path.isfile` and `subprocess call`

Other things that I tried:

> -added full image file path using string literal 'r'
>
> -tried different images and file types

Comment: Show the full traceback

Comment: @Chris_Rands Done. Thanks